# Microsoft Band SDK Sensors.Windows sample exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, microsoft-band

When I try to run the `Sensors.Windows` sample project for the Microsoft Band SDK (1.3.10417.1) on my Windows 10 machine I get the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.get_AppId()
   at Microsoft.Band.StoreApplicationPlatformProvider`2.GetApplicationIdAsync(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Band.BandClient.StartOrAwakeStreamingSubscriptionTasks()
   at Microsoft.Band.BandClient.SensorSubscribe(SubscriptionType type)
   at Microsoft.Band.Sensors.BandSensorBase`1.<>c__DisplayClass4.<StartReadingsAsync>b__3()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Band.Sensors.BandSensorBase`1.<StartReadingsAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at PunchingBand.Models.PunchingModel.<Connect>d__48.MoveNext()
```

It looks like it's throwing the exception because the SDK uses the `CurrentApp` which according to the remarks section [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator.aspx) on `CurrentAppSimulator` isn't possible if the app isn't listed in the Windows Store.

If the SDK needs access to `CurrentApp` how can I get this to work while developing my app?  It's not like I can swap `CurrentApp` with `CurrentAppSimulator` in a pre-compiled assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** This was fixed in Microsoft Band SDK version 1.3.10702.  If possible upgrade to that version otherwise use the hack below.

I figured out a hack to get this working after some investigation with .NET Reflector.  Just set a private field called `currentAppId` on the `BandClient` and the SDK won't attempt to get it from `CurrentApp`.  Right after a connection to the client is made and before attempting to stream any sensors run the following:

```cs
using (IBandClient bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]))
{
    Type.GetType("Microsoft.Band.BandClient, Microsoft.Band")
        .GetRuntimeFields()
        .First(field => field.Name == "currentAppId")
        .SetValue(bandClient, Guid.NewGuid());
```

Be sure to include a using for `System.Linq` and `System.Reflection`.  This is obviously a very hacky workaround so hopefully it's resolved in a future release of the Band SDK.